# How do I disable TSLint Rule: This rule requires the `strictNullChecks` compiler option to be turned on to function correctly

Tags: angular, eslint, jhipster, tslint

I am in the middle of upgrading our app and I'm getting the following error when i try to build my angular app:
This rule requires the `strictNullChecks` compiler option to be turned on to function correctly  @typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition

The problem is that I want "strictNullChecks" to be set to false so that I don't have to refactor the whole application until a later date. Is there a way to turn off this rule? I can't seem to find any documentation on this. I'm getting this same error about 2100 times. Anyone help would be appreciated.

I have tried adding the following to my angularCompilerOptions but that did not resolve my issue:
allowRuleToRunWithoutStrictNullChecksIKnowWhatIAmDoing: true

Comment: If you have a `.eslintrc` file, you could disable the rule there.

Answer (score 8):

I made next 3 steps to eliminate that error

1. Added to `.eslintrc.js` into `rules` section

> "@typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions": "warn"

2. Added to `tsconfig.json` into `jsoncompilerOptions` section

> "strictNullChecks": true

3. Reloaded my IDE

More information about this task

- at [Github](https://github.com/standard/eslint-config-standard-with-typescript/issues/481) in `eslint-config-standard-with-typescript` repo
- and at [TS ESLint website](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/strict-boolean-expressions/)